# User Login: login failed: 400 Bad Request

Tags: users, 8

I am trying the log in rest API with Drupal 8.4

For that, I am using **angular 5**

I have all the configurations working.

This is how I get the data from the form and send it to the UserServices. The UserServices will do the post method with the correct header, the user, and the password.

**onSubmit() getting the data from the form:**

```
onSubmit(name: string, pass:string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }    
    let user: any = {
     name: null,
     pass: null  
    };
    user.name = {value: name};
    user.pass = { "": pass};
    console.log('Json from the form ' +JSON.stringify(user));    
    this.UserService.login(user)
      .subscribe(user => {
        console.log('subscribed to login function' + JSON.stringify(this.user));
       });
}
```

**this is the login() function, that send the post method**

```
login (user: User): Observable<User> {
  const url = `${this.mainUrl}/user/login?_format=json`;  
  const postReturn = this.http.post(url, user, httpHaljson);      
console.log('Login return from the user service' + JSON.stringify(postReturn));  
return postReturn    
}
```

**This is my header** i have tested with aplication json and haplication hal json

```
const httpHaljson = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
  "X-CSRF-Token": "Qfnczb1SUnvOAsEy0A_xuGp_rkompgO2oTkCBOSEItM",
  "Authorization": "Basic Qfnczb1SUnvOAsEy0A_xuGp_rkompgO2oTkCBOSEItM", // encoded user/pass - this is admin/123qwe
  // "Content-Type": "application/hal+json"
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
};
```

**Now, this is what i get from the console:** User Login: login failed: Http failure response for http://drupal.dd:8083/user/login?_format=json: 403 Forbidden

This is how I send the data from the form: 
Json from the form {"name":{"value":"asd"},"pass":{"":"123"}}

Login return from the user service

```
{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":

{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":true,"value":

{"url":"http://drupal.dd:8083/user/login?_format=json","body":{"name":

{"value":"asd"},"pass":

{"":"123"}},"reportProgress":false,"withCredentials":false,"responseType":"

json","method":"POST","headers":{"normalizedNames":

{},"lazyUpdate":null},"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":

{},"map":null},"urlWithParams":"http://drupal.dd:8083/user/login?

_format=json"},"scheduler":null},"operator":{"concurrent":1}},"operator":

{}},"operator":{}}
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong? thanks! 
[image]

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: check the image, in the log, in the line "json from the form" I am sending in a wrong way the array with the user and the password. I recommend your do a console log with the data that you are sending and see if it's going in the way that drupal wants.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. my problem is the wrong username and password when I try with the correct username it is working fine but wrong username return 400 bad request how you handled that one?

Comment: look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
const headers= new Headers({ 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-CSRF-Token': 'Qfnczb1SUnvOAsEy0A_xuGp_rkompgO2oTkCBOSEItM',
  'Authorization': 'Basic Qfnczb1SUnvOAsEy0A_xuGp_rkompgO2oTkCBOSEItM'
})

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

login (user: User): Observable<User> {
  const url = `${this.mainUrl}/user/login?_format=json`;  
  return this.http.post(url, user, options ).map((res)=>{console.log(res)});      
}
```